# Give empty cells a different background color

Tags: css, css-tables

I was looking around the internet and couldn't find a solution to give empty cells in html/CSS a different background color.

While working on a system for festival production, I would like to draw attention of the producers (system users) to missing data in complex tables, by giving them an alerting color.

I know the background and the empty cell property of course, but there doesn't seem to be a combination, since the empty cell property only has hide, show and inherent. But I guess there is some solution somewhere...

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the CSS3 [`:empty` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo) to target empty elements and style them. Or use a bit of JS.

EDIT: Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rHkMX/

Comment: +1 `:empty` is the correct answer. Unless you need to support old versions of IE. In which case, you'll need to use a Javascript polyfill like http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answers. This works fine as long as I stick with html. But if the data comes from mysql, it's not. (sorry I didn't mention that, I should have known that fetching the data from mysql can have an influence)

My code looks like this:
'<td><?php echo $ageboortedatum; ?><br><?php echo $ageboorteplaats; ?></td>'

Comment: @user1627596 - the cell will still be empty if the two values aren't populated, right? does `:empty` not work? it should do. (maybe the `<br>` is making the browser think it's not empty, but there are ways around that, by not including it if the two variables are empty)

Comment: Thanks, yes, it will indeed be the <br> which causes the cell not being empty.

Comment: Now the cell has an element and isn't empty anymore. You could add a few CSS selectors `:only-child` for the different situations you can encounter and that may work in *good* browsers. If you can, try to put the HTML code of your table in a PHP variable (after evaluation of the PHP code) and replace known patterns of "empty" cells (according to us humans) by `<td></td>` (with `str_replace` maybe, no need for slower `preg_replace` imho). Err no, replace by `<td class="empty"></td>` for cross-browser styling with the help of a class.

Answer (score 6):

Use :empty

To see how to change the css background with jQuery, check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5sVAt/1/

Else, just do the CSS version

```
td:empty{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The CSS version is fine. No need for JS unless you need to support old versions of IE (and in that case a polyfill like Selectivizr would be best solution so you can carry on using the standard CSS for other browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can use :empty pseudo class, but I am not quite sure about the browser compatibility (because this is css3). But you can use javascript to check the td's content.

Example by using Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("td").each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "") $(this).css("background", "black");
    });
});
</script>
```

This will add a black background to each td where the cell html is empty.

Comment: Browser compatibility is fine for CSS `:empty`, unless you need to support old versions of IE. In that case, use Selectivizr to fix the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a class like `empty` to the cell and then set the `empty` class' background color to the color you want.